# Microphone doesn't work after rebooting on a Macbook 2.1

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, macbook, microphone

I am running Xubuntu 12.04 on a Macbook 2.1 intel duo. But the problem existed on Ubuntu 12.04 too.

After booting up, the internal microphone doesn't work. After opening the Pulse Audio settings and changing the configuration, it will work after. However after suspending or shutting down, the microphone will not work again until changing the configuration again, even though the actual config didn't change.

Right now I have to always switch between the Anglog Stereo Duplex and the Analog Surround 4.0... each time. Is there anyway to get this microphone issue fixed? It seems like a problem with Pulse Audio.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved the issue and so I'll answer my own question. I simply went to the Software Center and uninstalled **PulseAudio**. I have **Gnome ALSA Mixer** instead and everything seems to be working fine now.

It's not a technical answer, but it works and thats all that I want.

Comment: Contrats! An answer does not necessarily need to be technical. If it solves, it is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Device Input values under gstreamer-properties.

[Source](http://solancer.blogspot.in/2012/10/mic-not-working-in-ubuntu-1204-solved.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Turns out, my mute button could mute but not unmute.

Solution: go  to Pulse Audio Volume Control -> Output Devices -> Port: Speakers Then unmute with the speaker icon.